# How to use variable logger in method login if I initialize this variable in setUp method?

Tags: java, selenium

How to use variable logger in method `@Test` Login if I initialize this variable in `setUp` method? View picture please.

[image]

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Paste the code into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Base Class and initialize your extent report in the same.

```
public class BaseClass {
   public ExtentReports report;
   public ExtentTest logger;
     public BaseClass{
       report=new ExtentReports("C:\\POMFrameWorkDemo.html",false);
     }
}
```

Use inheritance with test class extending the BaseClass

```
    @Test
    public void testSteps{
        logger=report.startTest("Test_Name");
        log.info("Test started");
    }
```